# GitLab-Python API, create trigger function

Tags: python, triggers, gitlab, gitlab-ci

```
trigger = gl.project_triggers.create({}, project_id=1)
```

What should I put inside the "{}"?

Comment: You must read the docs.

Comment: problem solved, instead of using the GitLab-Python API, I use the GitLab webhook. I use Postman convert the webhook POST message into python code and then it works the same function as the GitLab-Python API